# Odd Syntax Error when trying to deploy app with apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

I'm learning about deploying flask apps using apache2.4 and mod_wsgi on an Ubuntu 16.04 server by building the simplest of "Hello, Word!" apps, but I encountered a weird syntax error related to my wsgi file and I'm stumped.

Apache seems to be running fine but when I hit the app's domain, I get apache's standard 500 error and the logs list the following:

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 28427:tid 140540431517440] mod_wsgi (pid=28427): Target WSGI script '/var/www/myapp.domain.com/myapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[wsgi:error] [pid 28427:tid 140540431517440] mod_wsgi (pid=28427): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/myapp.domain.com/myapp.wsgi'.
[wsgi:error] [pid 28427:tid 140540431517440] Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error] [pid 28427:tid 140540431517440]   File "/var/www/myapp.domain.com/myapp.wsgi", line 5, in <module>
[wsgi:error] [pid 28427:tid 140540431517440]     exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
[wsgi:error] [pid 28427:tid 140540431517440]   File "<string>", line 4
[wsgi:error] [pid 28427:tid 140540431517440]     deactivate () {
[wsgi:error] [pid 28427:tid 140540431517440]                   ^
[wsgi:error] [pid 28427:tid 140540431517440] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The syntax error referenced in the logs are pointing to code in my virtual environment’s activation script located at ./venv/bin/activate

I'm wondering if my use the venv module vs. virtualenv is causing this issue

Here is the content of my app's wsgi file (test is the name of the module were flask is instantiated):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
activate_this = '/var/www/myapp.domain.com/venv/bin/activate'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/myapp.domain.com')

from test import app as application
```

Comment: Why are you trying to `exec` that file as Python code? It's pretty clearly not Python code.

Comment: Are you trying to activate a virtualenv from within a running Python script? The `activate` script is a shell script, not Python code, and it's too late to activate the virtualenv anyway.

Comment: See I was confused about that too. I know it's shell script. I was following the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/) over at the flask website for configuring the .wsgi file. Very bottom. I'm starting to think it's only written for virtualenv and not venv

Comment: That's `activate_this.py`, not `activate` (and apparently virtualenv does try to support activation in a running interpreter, although it has exactly the caveats that made me think they wouldn't support it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `activate_this.py` script is not recommended even if you had got the name correct. For how to use a Python virtual environment with mod_wsgi see the documentation at:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Ensure you are also using daemon mode of mod_wsgi.

The details in that document are too much to replicate here and what method you use depends on how using mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by change the virtual environment which I built by 'python3 -m venv'. now I create the venv by [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation/), and then re-install the necessary modules.

The reason is that the venv created by python3 hasn't the script of **activate_this.py** which is important in writing the myapp.wsgi file.

In the [professional document](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html), the reason is following:

```
    When needing to activate the Python virtual environment from within the 
    WSGI script file as described, it is preferred that you be using the either 
    virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper to create the Python virtual environment. 
    This is because they both provide the activate_this.py script file which 
    does all the work of setting up sys.path. When you use either pyvenv or 
    python -m venv with Python 3, no such activation script is provided.
```

so good luck!

Answer (score -1):

No matter what follows the curly brace (a set or dict display or dict comprehension) `deactivate () {` will not be legal Python code. I do not see anything odd or mysterious about getting a SyntaxError when you try to run it.